# Question about an interpretation of the MRS

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, consumer-theory, marginal

Given the marginal rate of substitution of $x$ for $y$ : $\frac{u'(x)}{u'(y)} $

I know one can interpret this as the amount of $y$ one is willing to give up for an additional unit of $x$, or the amount of $y$ that has to be given to compensate the consumer for a loss of $x$.

But mathematically, is it saying, how much the consumer values the next unit of $x$, in terms of the next unit of $y$? or the marginal valuation of $x$ in terms of additional units of $y$?

Comment: The short answer is no. The marginal utility of $y$ is not in units of $y$, but in marginal utils. As such, you can't interpret it in the way you want to. You could say it is how much the consumer values the next unit of $x$, in terms of how much they value the next unit of $y$.

Comment: just a follow-up clarification question- how is your last sentence substantive different than what my interpretation? i.e. the marginal valuation of the next unity of x in terms of the next unit of y?

Comment: The way I parse your sentence, you are asking about $\frac{u'(x)}{\partial y} $ not $\frac{u'(x)}{u'(y)} $. Contrast the following:
1) (what you said)  the marginal valuation of the next unity of x in terms of **the next unit of y**

2) the marginal valuation of the next unity of x in terms of **the marginal value of the next unit of y**

Comment: Oh ok, that makes perfect sense. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing out the expression with Leibniz notation, we get $\frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{\frac{du}{dy}}$, or the marginal utility of $x$ divided by the marginal utility $y$.

For example, let's imagine I get 10 utils from another apple and 5 utils from another cabbage. In that case, the MRS is therefore $\frac{\frac{10 utils}{1 apple}}{\frac{5 utils}{1 cabbage}}$, or, $\frac{2 cabbage}{1 apple}$, matching the marginal rate of substitution of 2 cabbages per apple.

A bit of simplification will easily get you $\frac{dy}{dx}$, which is the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $x$, the interpretation we're familiar with.